# How to open unzip files in a unique folder each time on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

On my iOS application I'm unziping files in "app/temp" folder like this:

```
NSString *unzipFolder = [[CommonFunctions getCachePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/temp/"];
```

and once im done with it im deleting item with:

```
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unzipFolder error:&e];
```

Issue is that bcz im creating mulital copy of unzip files some of the files Images name are same and displaying wrong images, and i dont find error on why my deleting function does not work!

IS there any way that i can do unziping of folder on diffrent path for each message that open by user?
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you just asking how you can create a unique name for your unzipFolder each time instead of using the same name every time? Or is there a deeper question here?

Comment: Also, a minor note: `-[stringByAppendingPathComponent:]` adds the slashes for you; you shouldn't be adding them.

Comment: Thanks for that, It would be nice if i can open file in a unique folder and delete it when im done! Bez each messages content are getting override, when user open messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like all you're asking is how to generate a unique name for your `unzipFolder` each time.

Just don't use a hardcoded name. Almost anything will do. For example:

```
NSString *unzipFolderTemplate = [[CommonFunctions getCachePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.XXXXXX"];
char *template = strdup([template fileSystemRepresentation]);
if (mkdtemp(template)) {
  NSString *unzipFolder = [NSString stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:template
                                                                length:strlen(template)];
  free(template);
  // do the work
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:unzipFolder error:&e];
}
```

The nice thing about `mkdtemp` is that it creates the directory for you, and guarantees there are no race conditions, somehow-left-over directories, or other problems. It's also more secure against, say, someone writing a crack or other jailbreak hack that exploits your code by predicting the path. The downside is, of course, that you have to drop down to C strings (which means an explicit `free`). But, as I said, there are many possibilities, and almost anything will do.

Also, note that I'm using `@"temp.XXXXXX"`, not `@"/temp.XXXXXX/"`. That's because `-[stringByAppendingPathComponent:]` already adds any necessary slashes for you (that is, in fact, the whole point of the method), and directory-creation functions don't need a trailing slash, so both of the slashes are unnecessary.

Meanwhile, I'm still a bit confused by what you're trying to do. If you need to keep a unique folder around for each message, and delete the folder when you're done with that message, and you could have multiple messages open at once, you need some way to remember which folder goes with which message.

For that, create an `NSMutableDictionary` somewhere, and right after the `free(template)` you'll want to do something like `[tempFolderMap addObject:unzipFolder forKey:messageName]`. Then, when closing a message, you'll do `[tempFolderMap objectForKey:messageName]` and use the result to the `removeItemAtPath:error:` message (and then you can also remove the key from `tempFolderMap`).

Comment: SO In my app i have list of messages downloaded from server, store it in database as a zip-folder and show like a email list when when user click on a message , im unzipping message and displaying in a web-view. as a each item click i want some place that i can unzip files from database and display html in web-view. the problem im having is that some reason temp folder is not getting deleted properly! and displaying previous images that user view in unzip folder. many thanks :)